# python mock responses with url parameters

Tags: python, mocking, python-responses

I have this URL and im successfully able to call this responses.

https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/?page=1&page_size=5

Now, I'm trying to mock the responses and testing my api but mock throws a `ConnectionError`

```
with responses.RequestsMock() as rsps:
    url = 'https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/?page=1&page_size=5'
    rsps.add(responses.GET, url,
                     body=mocked_json, status=status_code,
                     content_type='application/json')
```

Error:-

```
ConnectionError: Connection refused: GET https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses?page=1&page_size=5
```

Comment: I get a 403 when I hit that URL directly.... It seems that you need some headers or auth to get in

Comment: Yes, it needs a authorization header, should I pass the same while mocking as well?

Comment: If that makes the ConnectionError stop, then yes. If not, it would help to see the entire traceback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [requests_mock](https://pypi.org/project/requests-mock/)

Do something like:

```
url = 'https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/?page=1&page_size=5'
expected_response = get_test_mock_response()

with requests_mock.mock() as req_mock:
    req_mock.get(url, text=expected_response, status_code=200)

    res = call_real_request_method()
    assert res == expected_response, 'Bad response received'
```

Try it's documentation, you can do many cool stuff with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code is not complete, but i adapted some example based on your example.

```
import responses
import requests

with responses.RequestsMock() as rsps:

    url = 'https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/?page=1&page_size=5'
    mocked_json = '{"key": "value"}'
    status_code = 200

    rsps.add(
        responses.GET, 
        url,
        body=mocked_json,
        status=status_code,
        content_type='application/json'
    )

    resp = requests.get('https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/?page=1&page_size=5')
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```